Why does a 1:1 transformer preserve voltage?
In the context of transformers, it seems intuitively obvious about winding ratios; for example doubling the coils on the second winding doubles the voltage.
But this seems to skip over the question of why was the voltage preserved in the 1:1 transformer in the first place?  If I have a coil adjacent to another coil, how does the second coil know the voltage of the first coil?

I am not an EE, but I'm thinking that maybe you should think of a 1:1 transformer as preserving impedance, and more generally, you may want to think of an arbitrary transformer as maintaining a fixed ratio of input impedance to output impedance.

Voltage Ratio = Turn Ratio. What else do you need to know? If you input 120 volts on the primary of a 1:1 transformer, you will have 120 volts on the output.
If you have a 1:2 turn ratio and input 120 volts, you get 240 output. In reverse, you step the voltage down, say 240 input with 120 volts output.

Captain, Good question. Faraday's Law was something newly observed and at the time could not be derived from any other physical law. It totally added something completely new. There are some good experimental setups (I'm thinking of one that uses a solenoid and a separate loop of wire attached to an ammeter around the solenoid body, with a ramped current at rate x, followed by holding that current steady for a time, followed by a down-ramped current at rate x/2 and studying the results. The math that flows out from there provides your answer. Not sure it will be presented in detail here. +1

@Dereck Yes, I know the rule about ratios, and like I mentioned, it's abundantly clear and intuitive that for example doubling the output coils doubles the voltage.. but why is the voltage matched in the first place?  Correlated, sure, but why exactly the same?  If I run a magnet across a coil, it creates current but the voltage is not so specific.

If two coils have the same magnetic flux in common, and they have the same number of turns, then the emf generated in each is the same. If you neglect parasitic effects, such as the resistance of the coils, and assuming the there is no core saturation or other fact that brings non-linearity into the picture, then if you apply an alternating voltage source across one coil, which is for that reason called the primary, then a back emf must be generated by changing flux in that coil that matches the applied emf. (Suppose that were not the case. Then, the current in the coil would have to increase, which, in turn would cause the back emf to rise). But since that back emf in the primary is also common to the other coil, then the same emf must be generated in the other coil, i.e. the secondary.

It comes from Faraday's law of indcution.
If a certain AC voltage with a certain number of turns causes a certain magnetic flux in the core, then in reverse, this same magnetic flux causes an equal AC voltage in equal number of turns.
In a transformer with two windings, the voltage applied to primary just generates the flux and that flux generates a voltage in the secondary. With equal number of turns, the voltages are equal. Assuming an ideal transformer with no resistive and magnetic losses.

To quibble, it is the current in the primary that creates the flux, not the voltage.

$V = N\dfrac{d\Phi}{dt}$ without one mention of current.

This is a very good answer to the question, especially the last paragraph. The question seems to be more qualitative or intuitive than it is quantitative.

@MathKeepsMeBusy 'Create' implies causation. Faraday's laws say nothing about causation. See Andy's comment about the flux being defined by the voltage. As it happens, the flux and current are related, but not by a causative link.

@Andyaka and yet there is magnetic flux associated with a DC current when there is no induced EMF.

@MathKeepsMeBusy I'm not quibbling either way. I agree that flux is made by current but, what I am saying is that it is exactly equal to the integral of voltage i.e. $\Phi = \frac{1}{N} \int V dt$ and by the other law $\frac{1}{L}\int V dt = I$ hence, the current got there due to the integration of voltage.

@Andyaka That integral of voltage is an indefinite integral. One cannot calculate the flux from the voltage alone without assuming some constant of integration. One can however, calculate the flux from the current alone.


If you apply an AC voltage to a coil a flux will be generated.

If a coil is "exposed" to flux lines there's going to be a voltage across it.


This is explained by the Faraday Equation:
$$
\mathrm{V_t = N \ \frac{d\Phi}{dt}}
$$
NOTE: I deliberately omitted the negative sign.
From the equation above:

If you apply \$\mathrm{V_t}\$ across an N-turn winding it'll generate a changing flux, \$\mathrm{d\Phi/dt}\$.
A changing magnetic flux of \$\mathrm{d\Phi/dt}\$ generates a voltage of \$\mathrm{V_t}\$ across an N-turn winding.

Consider a multiple-winding transformer with a magnetic core (e.g. ferrite). If you apply an AC voltage across one winding, it'll generate a changing flux. The flux lines will be "carried" or "transferred" (for the sake of simplicity) along the magnetic core. Any other windings that are "exposed" to these flux lines will generate voltage, regardless of the total number of windings.
Of course, the generated voltage will be proportional to the number of turns, as per the equation above (Saturation and other non-linear effects are ignored for the sake of simplicity).
For further details, consider studying "magnetic circuits".

Does this also apply for a DC current on a square wave?  (e.g. if you rapidly switch on/off a 5v signal, will you get a 5v square wave on the other side?)

@CaptainCodeman Yes but that will result in core saturation after some time. The volt-second balance needs to be maintained i.e. if you apply a positive DC for some time you need to apply a negative DC for some other time to ensure proper "core reset". Imagine the BH (hysteresis loop) here. Square wave with positive peaks only has a DC component. And a constant DC component will push the swing on BH loop upwards (or downwards, depending on the polarity) every cycle which will result in saturation. You'll need to apply the voltage through a large enough series capacitance.

The voltage in the secondary need not be the same as in the primary. It can be arbitrary or even negative depending on how you orient the two loops mutually in space. This orientation will determine the amount of primary magnetic flux passing through the secondary.
However, when using a low reluctance magnetic core, it is possible to guide the flux along specific paths and this makes it possible to channel close to 100% of the flux from the primary also through the secondary.

The designer determines the voltage. Turns Ratio = Voltage ratio. For example, if you want a 1:1 transformer, you, the designer, determine the frequency and voltage range. Say you want a 120 VAC @ 60 Hz 1 kVA transformer. You design the transformer to operate in the 60 Hz range, which determines the number of turns and material required in the primary and secondary. You select the wire size based on the current and insulation resistance based on the highest possible voltage for safety.
Input 120 Volts, you will have 120 volts. Input 60 volts and you get 60 volts out. As long as you stay with the design parameters, mostly for safety and voltage you want.
Use 2:1 input 240, you get 120 out. With 1:2 120 in, 240 out.

I think the OP understood all of that as indicated in the first paragraph of the question. The question was "... how does the second coil know the voltage of the first coil?"


... how does the second coil know the voltage of the first coil?

Only indirectly, via the flux in the core. The rate of change of flux gives the induced voltage per turn in all coils linked to that flux, both primary and secondary. More turns, more voltage, same turns, same voltage.

It may be worthwhile to remember that energy does not flow through the wires, but in the space around the wires.
What we consider electricity is simply the transmission of a certain potential energy over distances, thanks to proper guidance of the electric field.
Have a look at this divulgative site for additional descriptions.

This doesn't answer the question, I'm afraid.

@Transistor "If I have a coil adjacent to another coil, how does the second coil know the voltage of the first coil?"
